# Adding +1 to a variable inside a function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

So basically I have no idea what is wrong with this small piece of code, and it seems like I can't find a way to make it work.

```
points = 0

def test():
    addpoint = raw_input ("type ""add"" to add a point")
    if addpoint == "add":
        points = points + 1
    else:
        print "asd"
    return;
test()
```

The error I get is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'points' referenced before assignment
```

Note: I can't place the "points = 0" inside the function, because I will repeat it many times, so it would always set the points back to 0 first.
I am completely stuck, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also pass points to the function:
Small example:

```
def test(points):
    addpoint = raw_input ("type ""add"" to add a point")
    if addpoint == "add":
        points = points + 1
    else:
        print "asd"
    return points;
if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = 0
    for i in range(10):
        points = test(points)
        print points
```

Comment: This is the proper design pattern, and should be the selected answer, as it fixes the root of the problem instead of creating a work around for a poorly designed function.

Answer (score 32):

`points` is not within the function's scope. You can grab a reference to the variable by using [nonlocal](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt):

```
points = 0
def test():
    nonlocal points
    points += 1
```

If `points` inside `test()` should refer to the outermost (module) scope, use [global](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt):

```
points = 0
def test():
    global points
    points += 1
```

Comment: +1 for `nonlocal`, though I favour Xeun's solution.

Comment: When defining that first test() function, I get a Syntax Error: no binding for nonlocal 'points' found, even though I already defined points = 0, as you did above. 'global' worked, but not the 'nonlocal'.

Answer (score 0):

Move points into test:

```
def test():
    points = 0
    addpoint = raw_input ("type ""add"" to add a point")
    ...
```

or use [global statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), but it is bad practice.
But better way it move points to parameters:

```
def test(points=0):
    addpoint = raw_input ("type ""add"" to add a point")
    ...
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I can't move it into test because it would set it back to 0 everytime I called test(), but thanks for the answer